# Ajax won't call controller method mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, inline-editing

I am trying to do inline editing by cell, not by row, upon a double click. This much works but it won't update the record- the "SaveCustomer" call to controller isn't made. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

here is my index view file (part of it, the rest is irrelevant)

```
   @foreach (var item in Model.Drivers)
        {
            <tr id="@item.ID">
                <td id="id">
                     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                </td>
                <td id="lastName">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td id="firstName">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) 
                </td>
                <td id="seniority">
                  @if (item.Seniority != null) {@Convert.ToDateTime(item.Seniority).ToShortDateString()}                                      
                </td>
                <td>
                <td> //more go here </td>
```

Then here is the javascript file- sorry for the formatting, happens everytime I copy&paste

```
 $("td").dblclick(function () {
if (!$(this).hasClass("edit")) {
    var value = jQuery.trim($(this).html());
    $(this).html("<input id=\"txtEdit\" type=\"text\" class=\"textbox\" value=\"" + value + "\" onblur=\"SaveValue(this, '" + value + "')\" onfocus=\"PutCursorAtEnd(this)\" />");
    $(this).addClass("edit");
    $("#txtEdit").focus();
}
});

 function PutCursorAtEnd(obj) {
if (obj.value == obj.defaultValue) {
    $(obj).putCursorAtEnd(obj.length);
}
}

function SaveValue(obj, oldValue) {
var value = $(obj).val();
$(obj).parent().removeClass("edit");
if (value != oldValue) {
    var property = $(obj).parent().attr("id");
    var id = $(obj).parent().parent().attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveCustomer", "save")',
        data: { ID: id, Property: property, Value: value },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: SaveCustomer_Success,
        error: Error
    });
 }
else {
    $(obj).parent().html(oldValue);
}
}

function SaveCustomer_Success(data, status) {
$(data.d.ID).parent().html(data.d.NewValue);
}
```

and lastly here is the controller method

```
    public object SaveCustomer(int ID, string Property, string Value)
    {
        Driver driver = unitOfWork.DriverRepository.GetByID(ID);
        switch(Property) {
            case "id":
                driver.ID = Convert.ToInt32(Value);
                break;
            case "firstName":
                driver.FirstName = Value;
                break;
            case "lastName":
                driver.LastName = Value;
                break;
            case "seniority":
                driver.Seniority = Convert.ToDateTime(Value);
                break;
        }
        unitOfWork.DriverRepository.Update(driver);
        unitOfWork.Save();

        return new
        {
            ID = ID,
            NewValue = Value
        };
    }
```

Much help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in SaveCustomer()? Does it get hit?  Shouldn't the SaveCustomer controller method be returning an ActionResult? What does the route look like?

Comment: Where is the SaveValue js function called?

Comment: This is fantastically brittle code. I can easily see multiple points of failure and it's a maintenance nightmare. Honestly, I'd recommend starting over, preferably guided by some tutorials or articles you should be able to turn up on a simple Google Search (this is a fairly common scenario). Even if you fix this immediate problem, you'll be coming back for endless rounds of additional SO questions to make this function properly.

Comment: @JamesLawruk I did put a breakpoint in the function and no it didn't get hit.

Comment: and @BobMac it's called within the first function     $(this).html("<input id=\"txtEdit\" type=\"text\" class=\"textbox\" value=\"" + value + "\" onblur=\"SaveValue(this, '" + value + "')\" onfocus=\"PutCursorAtEnd(this)\" />");

Comment: _url: '@Url.Action("SaveCustomer", "save")'_ I assume your controller is named `saveController`

Comment: can you open your script debugger tools and check whether there is any error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove following line from your ajax options because you are not sending `json` type data.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Since you are sending a `POST` request you have to add `HttpPost` attribute to controller. And also you are expecting `json` result, so your controller should be like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveCustomer(int ID, string Property, string Value)
{
    /// ...
    return Json(new { ID = 1, NewValue = 1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing data, contentType and dataType from Ajax call and change the url to:

```
url: 'save/SaveCustomer?ID=' + id + '&Property=' + property + '&Value=' + value,
```

put a break point in the controller to see if the call hits it.  There is no reason why it will not.

Use Chrome browser and open JavaScript console.  You will see why it doesn't work, if it doesn't work after this change.